# Push values to array, and print values from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make js class where I will do following. Send car name (txt) with usages (number). For two kinds of cars I have some calculations then I need to store those values in array. 
After I store in array I need to do it again and store in same array.
Once I complete I need to print data out of array with usages desc.
I don't know if my logic is ok, as I am starting learning JS some advices or class solution will me a lot.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="text" id="vrijednost">
    <button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"><p>
</body>
<script src="cons.js"></script>
<script>
    function submit(){
        name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        vrijednost = document.getElementById('vrijednost').value;

        test = new CarUsage(name, vrijednost)
        console.log(test.get());

    } 
</script>

class CarUsage{

    constructor(total, car){}

    calCarUsage(name, usage){

        let car = {     
            carName: name,   
            carUsage: usage    
        };

        if(car.carName=='Mercedes'){
            this.car = "Mercedes";          
            this.total = 20 + usage * 10;  
            return store(this.car, this.total) 
        }

        else if(car.carName==='Golf'){ 
            this.car = "Golf";
            this.total = 800; 
            return store(this.car, this.total)
        }           
        else{
            this.car === "Other";
            this.total === '160' ;

            return store(this.car, this.total)

        }

    }

    store(name, usage){ 
        var usages = {carName:name, usage:usage};  
    }

    get(){
        for(i=0;i<usages.length;i++){
            alert("Car:- "  + usages[i].carName + "Usage:- "  + usages[i].usage);
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: You haven't shown any attempts at pushing into an array in your code,did you have an attempt

Comment: I have tried, but this confuses me. return store(this.car, this.total) Idk if this is correct way of doing it.

Comment: koliko ja vidim class ti se nalazi izvan script taga

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your trying to achieve here: 
But regarding arrays and how you add items and print its values, heres one way of achieving it:

```
 var sentence = []
    var words = ['this', 'is', 'one', 'way', 'of', 'push', 'to', 'an', 'array','and','print', 'the', 'values']
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
     sentence.push(words[i]);
    }
    console.log("Here's my sentence: " + sentence.join()) // => Here's my sentence: this is one way of pushing to an array and print the values
```

or if you simply want to print each item in the array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++){
 console.log(sentence[i]);
}
```

Comment: I get "name" and "vrijednost" from input fields, according to name I do some calculations and I need to push that to array. I am not sure in if statement can i call method like this return store(this.car, this.total). when I do console.log it says undefinded.

Comment: Your store function doesnt returen anything. It oboy declares a variable. Thats why you get undefined. Also, your usages variable inside the store function is not an array, its an object. [] = array. {} = object. In short youd need to return the users variable from your store function.